# Does JVM cacerts import require tomcat reboot?

Tags: linux, tomcat, java

We have `JDK 1.5.0_11` version running, and i have just recently add new certificate in `/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_11/jre/lib/security/cacerts`  but question is does it require tomcat restart to reload this file? or is there any work around to load in realtime It is production that is why i am asking...

Comment: Update your JDK right now. Java 5 ist dead for years and you even do not have the most recent one of Java 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have test scenario on TEST server and result it doesn't require reboot or reload tomcat.